# Exact data under certain month and year

Tags: excel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFmKU.png)

Hello everyone,

I encountered difficulties when searching a value among the data within dates, months and years. I had no problem in using MAX, MIN etc...the basic elements in elements. But when it comes to exacting a value from specific month and year, i was really stuck in there.

1) I need to choose and highlight only the value in Column C if it is the first day of the month.
2) Find the Max and min value among column C to F in each month.
3) Compare the Max and min value with highlighted value in 1). it should be done in each month respectively.

I believe 3) can be achieved if 1) and 2) are done. I got almost 10 years of similar data and will need to repeat above procedure to obtain these value month by month. Can anyone advise where should i start? (i am still googling it..)

BIG THANKS!

Comment: Not sure if u can see the picture..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFmKU.png

Comment: If you '*encountered difficulties*' then you must have tried something. EDIT YOUR QUESTION TO INCLUDE YOUR OWN EFFORT. Paste the sample data directly into your question; it is just plain rude and discourteous to expect others to retype your data in order to proof a solution just because you are too lazy to figure out how to copy and paste data into your question.